# Swift Equivant to Python's - hash.digest().encode('base64').strip()?

Tags: python, ios, swift, base64, md5

Basically I'm trying to convert my Python code to Swift, and can't seem to find an equivalent/alternative for this line of code (md5 Hash Digest to base64):

```
return hash.digest().encode('base64').strip()
```

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32041572/3697446

It returns a 24-character String, which is exactly what is needed for my usage.  I tried using this for base64 but creates a string much to long (I'm guessing because it was base64 encoding the hexdigest rather than digest?):

```
func toBase64(url: String) -> String{
    let data = url.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
}
```

This is my md5 set up (with bridging header for CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h):

```
func md5(string string: String) -> String {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }

    var digestHex = ""
    for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
        digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
    }

    return digestHex
}
```

any help is much appricieated!

Comment: You are guessing correctly ...

Comment: @martin-r do you know how I would get the digest rather than the hexdigest? (if thats what your trying to say) I've tried a few things but got nowhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are saying yourself, your `md5(string:)` is an equivalent to `hexdigest`, not `digest`.
The result of md5 digest is a byte sequence, and you'd better hold it in `NSData` in Swift.

With defining this:

```
func md5Data(string string: String) -> NSData {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }

    let digestData = NSData(bytes: digest, length: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    return digestData
}
```

You can write something like this:

```
let result = md5Data(string: "test").base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
print(result) //->"CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g=="
```