# Converting CryptoJS Base64 Encode to Python

Tags: python, base64, cryptojs

I have the following piece of code that just encodes a value into Base64 using javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script>
var magic = "TEST";

var magic1 = CryptoJS.MD5(magic).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
document.write(magic1);

</script>
```

Output from the above leads to:

```
AzvZSxFo1+Tw1kTDyV41vw==
```

Now when I want to do the same in python I'm getting a different result:

```
import hashlib
import base64

magic = "TEST"
magic = hashlib.md5(magic.encode())
magic = magic.hexdigest()  
magic1= base64.b64encode(magic.encode())
print(magic1)
```

Output from the above leads to:

```
   MDMzYmQ5NGIxMTY4ZDdlNGYwZDY0NGMzYzk1ZTM1YmY=
```

Why am I getting two different base64 results for the exact same string? How should I adapt my python code to work then?

**EDIT**
I've made a complete update as suggested that shows working code for both instances. I'd like to understand why there is a difference between the java and python result. How can I obtain the same result on python.

Comment: so what is your goal in the above code? The javascript result is correct base64 code if you treat `magic`as hexadecimal representation of a binary number, the python code treats `magic` just as a string and has a correct result for that case. But in the first case the javascript code seems to be incomplete, at least I can't reproduce it with the given two lines.

Comment: the magic is actually an MD5 hash that is generated and then converted to base64. I want to fully replicate and get the same result in python that I have in javascript. So if I understand you correctly I have to let python treat the valude as hexadecimal of a binary?

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solve it.

```
import hashlib
import base64

magic = "TEST"
magic = hashlib.md5(magic.encode())
magic = magic.digest()  
magic1= base64.b64encode(magic)
encodedStr = str(magic1, "utf-8")
print(str(encodedStr))
```

Change was to not use digesthex but instead use digest instead:

```
AzvZSxFo1+Tw1kTDyV41vw==
```

The below link was helpful in solving my problem:

[Python, get base64-encoded MD5 hash of an image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038881/python-get-base64-encoded-md5-hash-of-an-image-object)